# Interact with Ruby script after it runs

Tags: ruby, irb

I am used to do the following in IPython:

```
run foo
```

And it will load the file foo.py. Then every variable that was defined in the file will be in scope. Now I am learning Ruby. I have a hello.rb file which only have the following:

```
puts "Hello"
x = 1
```

When I load it in irb with

```
load './hello.rb'
```

The terminal prints on the screen "Hello". But I don't get to play with the variable x.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby you cannot access local variables defined in required files. In irb file's local variables are out of scope.

There are a few things you can do to solve this:

- Define a constant:

  ```
  #hello.rb
  module SharedConst
  X = 1
  end
  puts "Hello"

  #in irb
  puts SharedConst::X
  # => 1
  ```
- Define instance variables

  ```
  #hello.rb
  puts "Hello"
  @x = 1

  #in irb
  @x
  # => 1
  ```

Comment: Or use a tool like [pry](http://pryrepl.org/), which lets you open a REPL in any scope to access the local variables.